# Class not starting off from the main file in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm facing a problem which has puzzled me regarding android. I've written a contentprovider for an app with properly defined Provider node under the Manifest file. Typically when an app is started and stepped through under debugger it should start from the onCreate of the main file but mine didn't. Debugger showed that it stepped through the ContentProvider which is giving me alot of problems ... does anyone know anything about it ? THanks !

My android manifest is as such ... quite straight forward :) Cant find answer :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MedF1"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name=".DrugProvider"
        android:authorities="com.paad.provider.drug"/>
</application>
```

Comment: It might help if you posted your AndroidManifest.xml